# MySQL: comparison of integer value and string field with index

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

Table `a_table` has index on `string_column`.
I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE string_column = 10;
```

I used `EXPLAIN` to find that no indexes are used.
Why? Could you help me with MySQL documentation link?

Updated: [Sandbox (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7663/1)

Comment: Refer to this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-indexes.html ..   3rd bullet point `Comparison of dissimilar columns may prevent use of indexes if values cannot be compared directly without conversion. Suppose that a numeric column is compared to a string column. For a given value such as 1 in the numeric column, it might compare equal to any number of values in the string column such as '1', ' 1', '00001', or '01.e1'. This rules out use of any indexes for the string column.`

Comment: Actually, 10 is not a column (I saw this text in documentation before). So it can be converted to string of necessary type.

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4807/1 for string to int conversion index is used while for int to string it does not follow even though I use `force index`..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The essential point is that the index cannot be used if the database has to do a conversion on the table-side of the comparison.

Besides that, the DB always coverts Strings -> Numbers because this is the deterministic way (otherwise 1 could be converted to '01', '001' as mentioned in the comments).

So, if we compare the two cases that seem to confuse you:

```
-- index is used
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE int_column = '1';
```

The DB converts the string '1' to the number 1 and then executes the query. It finally has int on both sides so it can use the index.

```
-- index is NOT used. WTF?
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE str_column = 1;
```

Again, it converts the string to numbers. However, this time it has to convert the data stored in the table. In fact, you are performing a search like `cast(str_column as int) = 1`. That means, you are not searching on the indexed data anymore, the DB *cannot* use the index.

Please have a look at this for further details:

- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/numeric-strings
- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions/case-insensitive-search

Comment: is there a way to let MySQL throw the error since the column type and the value type don't match?